# How to parse json using a generic function?

Tags: java

I want to write a generic function to parse a json string (stringEtcdContent below in the code). The string has a list of objects with the key "value". I parse the json into a tree, get a list of JsonNode's (valueNodes below) with the string to parse using a generic class. The class in which I have the function is this: "public abstract class DashboardReportProvider". Based on a similar question here, I wrote this function:

```
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public List<T> getStatusList(String path) {
    Class<T> clazz;
    clazz = (Class<T>) ((ParameterizedType) this.getClass().getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    List<T> statusList = new ArrayList<>();
    T statusItem;
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    try {
      String stringEtcdContent = etcdCommandExecutor.getEtcdValue(path);
      JsonParser parser=new MappingJsonFactory().createParser(stringEtcdContent);
      JsonNode rootNode=parser.readValueAsTree();
      List<JsonNode> valueNodes=rootNode.findValues("value");
      Iterator<JsonNode> valueNodesIterator=valueNodes.listIterator();
      while (valueNodesIterator.hasNext()) {
        JsonNode valueNode=(JsonNode)valueNodesIterator.next();
        ObjectWriter writer = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter();
        String valueString = writer.writeValueAsString(valueNode);
        statusItem = mapper.readValue(valueString, clazz);
        statusList.add(statusItem);
      }
      return statusList;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      LOG.error(e.getMessage());
    }
    return statusList;
  }
```

It compiles fine, but when I try to run the code, I get this error:
"[ERROR] java.lang.Class cannot be cast to java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType". What is wrong?

Comment: Class is an object that implements several interfaces, including interface Type.
You attempt casting ParameterizedType to Class

Comment: However, ParameterizedType doesn't not extend all the same interfaces as Class implements, hence this casting is impossible

Answer (score 0):

Try ObjectMapper ,

```
new ObjectMapper().readValue(path,Object.class);
```

where Object.class - cast to type